# What's the minimum amount of space I could leave for Windows 10 in a dual boot setup?

Tags: dual-boot, storage

I've just bought a new laptop. It's intended to be primarily for Linux and teaching myself JavaScript. I already use a Mac as my main laptop so won't be installing many (Windows) apps, or storing large amounts of media.

I want to keep Windows around both to make it easy to restore the laptop for selling or gifting later, and as a 'just in case' for home Windows need.

What's the smallest space you'd recommend leaving Windows in, and what would you put as a reasonable size NTFS shared drive - again just functional, not serious storage?

The specs - i3/ 4gb/ 1tb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft recently updated the [minimum hardware requirements](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/minimum/minimum-hardware-requirements-overview#331-storage-device-size). For updated versions of Windows 10 (1903) they now recommend "32 GB or greater" for both 32bit and 64bit.

I personally recommend at least 50 GB, but that heavily depends on the use case.

Answer (score 0):

This is Windows 10 minimum requirements:
Hard disk space: 16 GB for 32-bit OS 20 GB for 64-bit OS.

But its better to leave more disk space for working fine...